# does the jquery trigger('resize') function works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this 2 pieces of code

```
function fixFooter() {
    var wrapper = $('#disqus_wrapper').height();
    if ( wrapper > 200 ) { 
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
};

var element = $('#disqus_wrapper');
new ResizeSensor(element, function() {
    fixFooter();
});
```

The expected effect is that the window will resize every time the div#disqus_wrapper changes height. (to fix comments and footer overlapping)

Well the code works, but only once after the page loads. I need it to resize each time the div changes in height. I tried switching the trigger('resize') function with an alert and everything works perfectly. Any idea why the trigger('resize') only works once and how can I fix it?

Update ;

The html is just this because I am loading the Disqus comment system

```
<div id="disqus_wrapper"><div id="disqus_thread"></div></div>
```

For detecting the div height change I am using this library
https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries (the ResizeSensor.js)

Comment: Show us your event listener too.

Comment: @eisbehr , i'm using https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries to detect the height change. The detection works properly and when i use alert() it fires up everytime the div changed height.But it just work once when i use $(window).trigger('resize');

Comment: Post your Html and event listener please @Askaoru

Comment: and then You inspect `disqus_wrapper` element does it height changes?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan yep.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function `fixFooter()` in window resize event.

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
       fixFooter();
    });
```

Comment: that doesnt work :( and it gave me `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`